# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' -- trying to sum all integers in a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having difficulty outputting a sum of any group of integers i give my code as i am trying to be universal with it but all i get is an operand error where in this example i should get 7.

My code

```
 sum1 = input('Enter a set of integers: ')
 sum2 = sum(sum1)
 print('The sum of the integers entered are: ' , sum2)

line 2, in <module>
sum2 = sum(sum1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

my output should be 7 as i inputed: 5,2 but i get the error message, how can i fix this.

Comment: In python 3.x, values received through `input` are stored as strings. Hence, if you input `5,2` you actually will have `sum1 = "5,2"`. Before summing, you have first to parse that data for you to get a list of strings. With some quick google search, you'll find how to _convert a comma-divided string into a list of strings_ and how to _convert each member of a list to an integer_. Tips: you may use `str.split` method and `map(int, list_)`. Just then, after all that, you'll be able to `sum()`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to take the sum of the string `'5,2'`. This won't work. There's two steps you need to do to it first:

1. Split the string so that you have a list of things to take the sum of (with `split`). Now instead of `'5,2'`, you'll have `['5','2']`.
2. Convert the strings into numbers (with `int`, and `map` to do it to all of the pieces). Now, instead of `['5','2']`, you'll have `[5,2]`.

Put them together like this:

```
sum2 = sum(map(int, sum1.split(',')))
```

Comment: Consider the usual chiding re: answering an obvious duplicate to have taken place (ref: "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), 3rd bullet point). That said, this *is* a better answer than the linked duplicate has -- maybe move it there?